# PHP Image Upload doesn´t save file in folder

Tags: php

So im trying to upload pictures the script just dont save the image in the folder(/articles/uploads/)
Code:

PHP:

```
      $filename = $_FILES['ppicture']['name'];
      $tmp_name = $_FILES['ppicture']['tmp_name'];
      $filename = rand(9999,10000).date('Ydmhis').$filename;
      $uploadOk = 1;

        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {

                $errors = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</div>";
                $uploadOk = 0;

                }else{

                $uploadOk = 1;

                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '/articles/uploads/'.$filename);    }
```

Comment: you should not trust the `name` of the image that is uploaded. a remote user can just take malware, call it `whatever.jpg` and then upload it to your server. Use [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) on the file instead, and that should tell you the image type.

Comment: What error log says? I try, you have no access to `/articles/uploads`.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous problems (and potential problems) with your code:

1. `$filename = $_FILES['ppicture']['name']` will contain the *original* name of the file that was uploaded. When a file is uploaded, PHP renames this file to `tmp_name` instead, and that is where you should look for the file in your file system.
2. `name` cannot be trusted to determine `$imageFileType`. A bad guy could specify any arbitrary filename under the sun -- even for a file that was not an image. You should instead use `getimagesize` (see [the php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) for information).
3. your web server process running this script might not have access to the directory where you are trying to put the file - `/articles/uploads/`
4. You are trusting the contents of `name` to specify where the file gets put on your server. This is not safe, and your script could be exploited by a malicious user to put files in a spot that compromises your system.

Here is a modified version of your script that is not perfect, but should be safer, and includes various error checks to hopefully help you locate your problem:

```php
      $filename = $_FILES['ppicture']['name'];
      $tmp_name = $_FILES['ppicture']['tmp_name'];

      // you really should be more careful to screen this before just using it
      $filename = rand(9999,10000).date('Ydmhis').$filename;

      if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)) {
        throw new Exception("tmp_name was not an uploaded file! something was wrong!");
      }

      $imageInfo = getimagesize($tmp_name);
      if (!$imageInfo) {
        throw new Exception("imageInfo returned an empty value.");
      }
      $imageFileType = $imageInfo[2];

      $validImageTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000, IMAGETYPE_PNG);


      if (!in_array($imageFileType, $validImageTypes)) {
        $errors = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</div>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        
      } else {
        $destDir = "/articles/uploads/";
        if (!is_dir($destDir)) {
          throw new Exception("the destination directory is not a directory!");
        }
        if (!is_writable($destDir)) {
          throw new Exception("the destination directory is not writable!");
        }
        $destFile = $destDir . $filename; // THIS REALLY ISN'T SAFE UNLESS YOU PERFORM SOME VALIDATION ON THE FILENAME
        if (file_exists($destFile)) {
          throw new Exception("the file you are trying to upload already exists");
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destFile)) {
          $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
          throw new Exception("Unable to move uploaded file to destination");
        }
      }
```

EDIT: I had to fix an issue or two with my code. Please use this updated code instead.